# How can I reference a field from one event to another event in logstash?

Tags: regex, logging, logstash

I am currently working with logs with some of its content looking like this:

```
00:19:59.771 (07120/evtThread     ) TRC> Cem< [Core1] CALL_STATE... 
00:20:00.199 (05768/BCMApplicationThread) INF> 
#S#|Call stats, ongoing calls: 8, handled_calls: 7304
#S#+----------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
#S#|Peer                        |      From|        To|   MinTime|   MaxTime|   AvgTime|
#S#+----------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
#S#|        CallDispatcher:Core2|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
#S#|        CallDispatcher:Core3|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
#S#|                   Cem:Core1|      1632|      6207|         0|   5996522|    311685|
```

I parsed the line containing the time like this:

```
grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{TIME:time} (?<bcm_comp>\(\d{5}\/\w{4,}\:*\ *\w*\)) (?<loglevel>\w{3}>{1}) %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
    add_field => [ "BCM_System", "PROD" ]
}
```

The lines containing the #S# at the front was parsed like this. Disregard the lines containing -------- and the lines containing the title of the table and the call stats line.

```
grok {
    match => [ "message", "(?<start>\#\S\#\|)\s* (?<peer>\w*\:\w*)(?<div2>\|)\s* %{NUMBER:From}(?<div3>\|)\s* %{NUMBER:To}(?<div4>\|)\s* %{NUMBER:MinTime}(?<div5>\|)\s* %{NUMBER:MaxTime}(?<div6>\|)\s* %{NUMBER:AvgTime}(?<div7>\|)" ]        
    remove_field => [ "start", "div2", "div3", "div4", "div5", "div6", "div7" ]
    overwrite => [ "message"]       
    add_field => [ "reference_time", "%{@time}"]
}
```

What I am trying to do is take the time from the previous line and add it as a field for where I groked the #s# lines. I try using the add_field  syntax  from logstash as shown but it doesn't work...it just literally prints out %{@time}.

Is there any way I can somehow extract that time from the previous line and put it in a field for another event?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to write a filter plugin to do something like this as far as I know.  Here's a simple plugin I threw together to do something like that -- it memorizes a field when it sees it and then uses the last value it saw if it's not present.

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "logstash/filters/base"
require "logstash/namespace"
require "set"
#
# This filter will look for a field from an event and record the last value
# of it.  If it's not present, it will add the last value to the event
#
# The config looks like this:
#
#     filter {
#       memorize {
#         field => "time"
#         default => "00:00:00.000"
#       }
#     }
#
# The `field` is the name of the field that you want to memorize
# The `default` is the value to use for the field if you haven't seen it yet
#   in the file (this is optional)

class LogStash::Filters::Memorize < LogStash::Filters::Base

  config_name "memorize"
  milestone 1

  # The field to memorize
  config :field, :validate => :string, :required => true
  # the default value to use for the field if it's not seen before we need it
  config :default, :validate => :string, :required => false

  # The stream identity is how the multiline filter determines which stream an
  # event belongs to. See the multiline plugin if you want more details on how
  # this might work
  config :stream_identity , :validate => :string, :default => "%{host}.%{path}.%{type}"

  public
  def initialize(config = {})
    super

    @threadsafe = false

    # This filter needs to keep state.
    @memorized = Hash.new
  end # def initialize

  public
  def register
    # nothing needed
  end # def register

  public
  def filter(event)
    return unless filter?(event)

    if event[@field].nil?
      val = @memorized[@stream_identity]
      if val.nil?
        val = @default
      end
      event[@field] = val
      filter_matched(event)
    else
      @memorized[@stream_identity] = event[@field]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I dont know what you coded, Its default generated plugin. And not working for me

Comment: I rewrote this as a logstash plugin for logstash 5... See https://github.com/alcanzar/logstash-filter-memorize