# Logstash: How to save an entry from earlier in a log for use across multiple lines later in the log?

Tags: logstash

So the format of my logs looks somethings like this

```
02:00:30> First line of log for date of 2014-08-13
...
04:03:30> Every other line of log
```

My question is: how can I save the date from the first line to create the timestamp for the other lines in the files?

Is there a way to set some kind of "global" field that I can reuse for other lines?

I'm looking at historical logs so the current time isn't much use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a `memorize` filter that you could use to do that.  It was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24432297/2785358).

You'd use it like this:

```
filter {
   if [message] =~ /date of/ {
      grok {
        match => [ "message", "date of (?<date>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)" ]
      }
   } else {
      // parse your log with grok or some other method that doesn't capture date
   }
   memorize {
       field => date
   }
}
```

So on the first line, because you extract a date, it'll memorize it... since it's not on the remaining lines, it'll add the memorized date to the events.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same goal and am getting the following error: "Cannot use more than 1 filter worker because the following plugins don't work with more than one worker: memorize, memorize". Is there a way to make this filter thread-safe? Thanks