# Logstash - Use date present only once as a timestamp

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, timestamp, logstash

I have a type of log file that may contain lines with Java error descriptions. These lines are not timestamped, so I am trying to use another date that is only present once in my file as a timestamp for each match.

Is this possible? Can a field only matched once be added to every further matches?

Comment: Sounds like a possible [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you have multiple lines associated with a single event, you will probably want to combine them with the multiline filter/codec.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this answer I provided for a very similar question: [Logstash: How to save an entry from earlier in a log for use across multiple lines later in the log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384989/logstash-how-to-save-an-entry-from-earlier-in-a-log-for-use-across-multiple-lin/25385936#25385936) but there is a serious caveats:  If you "miss" the time line (for example if you restart logstash, or you don't have start_position=>beginning) then you will not get the timestamp.

The `memorize` fitler has been submitted as a pull request, so there's a chance it will be included in a future version of logstash.